# ASP Page with ReportViewer Control giving Access Denied Error

Tags: asp-classic, reportviewer

I am not from .Net background and thus need little help. We have a plain vanilla website which is used for publishing reports(hosted on SSRS 2008) through a reportviewer control in it.

We copied this website and moved it to a new standalone machine where IIS, SQL,SSRS all are hosted in a single place. After I login to the website(which authenticates a user from credentials stored in DB), it shows me list of reports but when I click on any one of them it just gives 1 line error:

Access Denied

No error codes get displayed, I do not see any errors in SSRS log(it usually records error if it denied access to a user) or SQL log or windows event log.

Please let me know what more information I can share to crack this. It appeared to me an issue with authentication as this is a standalone machine but then can't find which user is trying what.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks
Chandan Jha

Update:

Within a few minutes of posting question here on StackOverflow, I browsed some questions with similar nature and one of the posts did it!!

I went to my website in IIS,opened anonymous authentication, click edit from right side and then choose 'application identity pool' rather than specific user.

This solved my problem. May be this can help others. I cannot put this under answers as I have been lucky to find the solution within few minutes and website does not allow me to put it under answers for sometime.

Cheers!!
Long live stackOverflow

Comment: Please add the solution as a new answer, don't post it as part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Within a few minutes of posting question here on StackOverflow, I browsed some questions with similar nature and one of the posts did it!!

I went to my website in IIS,opened anonymous authentication, click edit from right side and then choose 'application identity pool' rather than specific user.

This solved my problem. May be this can help others.

PS: I could not add the answer earlier and I found it within few minutes of posting the question.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Do the Reports work, when you try them from SSRS-Frontend? As far as I can see the "access denied" can be between your website and SSRS or between SSRS and the DB it is querying.

Comment: I can see the data from the ReportServer and if there was an access denied error being thrown from the DB to SSRS it would have got reflected in SSRS logs. We are using admin roles for the time being to access anything and everything. Also when a dotnet friend tried to run the website in debug mode, we were able to see the reports nicely on the website.

Comment: Within a few minutes of posting question here on StackOverflow, I browsed some questions with similar nature and one of the posts did it!!

I went to my website in IIS,opened anonymous authentication, click edit from right side and then choose 'application identity pool' rather than specific user.

This solved my problem. May be this can help others.

Cheers!!
Long live stackOverflow